# Changing input style with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX code which is working properly, except the part where I want to add a class to the input field it just checked.

Input Field:

```
<input type="text" class="solution" id="input_rebus" name="answer" />
```

AJAX Code:

```
        $('.solution').on("change", function(){             
                var form_data = {
                name: $(this).val(),
                ajax: '1'
                    };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('homework/submit'); ?>",
                    type:'POST',
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(msg){
                        $('#message').html(msg);
                        this.addClass('solution_correct');
                        //outputs: Correct!
                        },
                    error: function(msg){
                        $('#message').html(msg);
                        this.addClass('solution_wrong');
                        //outputs: Wrong! Try again!
                        }

                    });

                return false;
            });
        </script>
```

So, the problem would be at the line "this.addClass('...');
I've tried using $(this), but that didn't work either.

It's probably something really stupid, but I can't seem to figure it out!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `context` property when calling $.ajax which will set to the `this` in all callbacks.

```
    $('.solution').on("change", function(){             
            var form_data = {
            name: $(this).val(),
            ajax: '1'
                };
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('homework/submit'); ?>",
                type:'POST',
                context: $(this),//<--- here
                data: form_data,
                success: function(msg){
                    $('#message').html(msg);
                    this.addClass('solution_correct');
                    //outputs: Correct!
                    },
                error: function(msg){
                    $('#message').html(msg);
                    this.addClass('solution_wrong');
                    //outputs: Wrong! Try again!
                    }

                });

            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

heres the way to do it

```
        $('.solution').on("change", function(){   
            var $self = $(this);         
            var form_data = {
            name: $(this).val(),
            ajax: '1'
                };
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('homework/submit'); ?>",
                type:'POST',
                data: form_data,
                success: function(msg){
                    $('#message').html(msg);
                    $self.addClass('solution_correct');
                    //outputs: Correct!
                    },
                error: function(msg){
                    $('#message').html(msg);
                    $self.addClass('solution_wrong');
                    //outputs: Wrong! Try again!
                    }

                });

            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Damn, didn't think of doing it like that. Works like a charm! Thanks!