# AJAX Call is not working even though the PHP and JS files work on their own

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've got an AJAX call set up. I've tested the JS file by alerting out the POST values I'm sending (and even alerting out the POST data string) and everything looks fine. I then take those values and put them in the PHP file where they are needed. I'm trying to replicate the process as easy as possible without any variables. It works fine. I then try to run the AJAX function and it gives me the error message. Here is my JS code (I declare the page_number and type variables earlier but it's not relevant; I've alerted those out and the variables are being assigned correctly):

```
$('.pagination_button').click(function(){

    //MAKE AJAX CALL TO REPOPULATE TABLE
    var myData = 'page_number='+ page_number + '&type='+ type;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', // HTTP method POST or GET
                url: 'archive_ajax.php', //Where to make Ajax calls
                dataType:'text', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                data:myData, //post variables
                success:function(response){

                //REFORMAT UPON SUCCESSFUL AJAX CALL
                $(this).parent().find('span.page_counter').text(next_page);
                $(this).closest('.archive_table').append(response);*/


                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert('didn\'t work'); //throw any errors
                }
            }); 
});
```

Here is the server side code. I've run this page by itself with variables and it displays everything correctly:

```
<?php
include('../includes/connect.php');

$page_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['page_number']);
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);

$start_number = $page_number*10;

if($type=="pagination_1"){
$type = "archive_1";
}
else if($type=="pagination_2"){
$type = "archive_2";
}
else if($type=="pagination_3"){
$type = "archive_3";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$type." ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT ".$start_number.", 10";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$converted = date('m/d/y', strtotime($row['timestamp']));
echo "<tr class='table_data' style='float:left;'>
<td>".$converted."</td>
</tr>";
}

?>
```

I can't seem to find where everything breaks down when it comes to actually sending the information to the server. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### EDIT

There I am getting (for those asking) is that it is alerting 'didn't work' from the error function. When I alert 'thrownError', it just says 'Not Found'. This, I'm assuming, means that it's not running the query successfully (which I'm not sure why).

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: your code snippet seems fine for me. If you want to track the data transfer, you can use the net gadget from Firebug.

Comment: *"and it gives me the error message"* <-- what error message?

Comment: Also please note that an attacker is perfectly able to select all rows from any table with your current code, which is a security issue, even though it is unlikely to yield much useful results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing input style with AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000604/changing-input-style-with-ajax)

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I just updated the error. It's not necessarily about updating the 'input', it's more about why the actual AJAX call isn't working. It looks like the query is not successfully running from what I can see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` inside the success-callback did not refer to the clicked element, it contains the options of the `$.ajax`-call.

Create a closure to get access to the clicked element inside the success-callback.

```
$('.pagination_button').click(function(){
  var that = this
  $.ajax({
           success:function(response){
                   //use here $(that) instead of $(this)
                   }
        }); 
});
```

Comment: That makes sense. I just updated the question as well. The problem is not necessarily the styling and jQuery code at this stage, it seems I'm getting an error and the AJAX call/query on the PHP page is not running successfully for some reason?

Comment: That actually answers my question. I figured something else out for the other issue. This work. Thanks!